# Incorrect output from Delphi TFormatSettings, ok in Windows, not in Android

Tags: android, delphi, locale, delphi-xe7

I am writing a multi-platform unit which includes the use of Delphi's TFormatSettings. I wish to create a global TFormatSettings to give me access to my home (UK) location information irrespective of the actual locale in which my code will be used (e.g I need UK decimal separator and list separator which varies by country). I simply want to read these values, not change them, or modify the actual machine locale. To test that I can get info this way I tried the code below. The code works fine in 32/64 Windows (returns the dollar sign followed by the British pound sign) but return the dollar sign for both outputs when run on Android on my 2yr-old Nexus 7.

It was created using XE7 and a multi-device application.

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  FS : TFormatSettings;
begin
  FS := TFormatSettings.Create( 'en-US' );
  ShowMessageFmt( FS.CurrencyString );

  FS := TFormatSettings.Create( 'en-UK' );
  ShowMessage( FS.CurrencyString );
end;
```

I've tried various other location strings but without success. I've traced deep into the 'LIBICU' code in SysUtils but I'm stretching the debugger and my knowledge! Can anyone comment of what I might be doing wrong? Thanks for any help.

Later edit SOLVED: To get UK in Android you need to pass 'en_GB' not 'en-UK'. There is a lot of useful info on [this Java link](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html)) shown by Uwe Raabe, too.

Comment: Is there any reason to believe that android should support multiple locales

Comment: @LURD wonder what that might be post scottish independence?!!!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, Great South Britain :-)

Comment: Brian, you can always hardcode a format setting to your liking, no need to rely on the system to have support for the UK setting.

Comment: @LU RD Yes, I'm probably being picky but I'm also learning how multi-platform (or not!) this XE7 stuff is. They've certainly worked hard in the RTL...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although it is possible that the requested locale is available, there is no guarantee:

(From http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html)

> Note that locale data is not necessarily available for any of the
>   locales pre-defined as constants in this class except for en_US, which
>   is the only locale Java guarantees is always available.
>
> It is also a mistake to assume that all devices have the same locales
>   available. A device sold in the US will almost certainly support en_US
>   and es_US, but not necessarily any locales with the same language but
>   different countries (such as en_GB or es_ES), nor any locales for
>   other languages (such as de_DE). The opposite may well be true for a
>   device sold in Europe.

I would expect at least an error message when the locale is not available, but the RTL seems to make a fallback on en_US in that case (see TFormatSettings.AdjustLocaleName).

Comment: Uwe that's great. Your link to the java locale made me look more carefully. To get UK in Android you need to pass 'en_GB' not 'en_UK'. There is a lot of useful info on that Java page, too.

Comment: I am not sure if there is a real difference between 'en_UK' and 'en_GB'. If it is not, then it should probably be handled inside `TFormatSettings.AdjustLocaleName'. It doesn't sound right to have to IFDEF the locale name in your application.

Comment: I have shown that 'en_GB' works cross platform now, but scared of issues later, I've now used 'en_US' and forced in my known (changed) items for UK. Messay but predicatable!